# How to Construct and Transform IO actions without using Monads

Tags: haskell

In the book "Haskell programming from first principles" it is said that:

> Monads are not, strictly speaking, necessary to Haskell. Although the
> current standard for Haskell does use monad for constructing and
> transforming IO actions, older implementations of Haskell did not.
> Monads are powerful and fun, but they do not define Haskell. Rather,
> monads are defined in terms of Haskell.

How did older implementations of Haskell constructed and transformed IO actions without using Monads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy with Class](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/history.pdf) (see Section 7), two main approaches were stream-based IO and continuation-based IO.

In stream-based IO, your `main` program is a function `[Response] -> [Request]`, to which the run-time system supplies a magic lazy input list. Then the output is evaluated, to see what request the program produces; some system call is made and the response is fed into the input list. You do need to be careful when writing `main` that it does not look at its inputs before having output a corresponding request.

In continuation-based IO, there is an abstract type of `Behaviour` (which in particular was defined as the above `[Response] -> [Request]` type, but the point is it doesn't have to be), and IO primitives take a continuation to be applied to their results.

```hs
Behaviour :: Type

getLine :: (String -> Behaviour) -> Behaviour
putStrLn :: String -> (() -> Behaviour) -> Behaviour  -- or equivalently,  String -> Behaviour -> Behaviour
```